# Why is engineering all smashed into one SE?

Tags: discussion

To a mechanical engineer like me, it appears that SO, Software Engineering SE, Computer Science SE, and Computer Graphics SE are really similar. In fact, reading other meta posts, it sounds like sometimes they have trouble sorting out how they're differentiated. Certainly for a non-expert like me, it takes some work to decide which one to even post in.

Contrast this with Engineering SE. A petroleum engineer and an aerospace engineer likely have far less overlapping knowledge than a typical expert from SO and software engineering SE. So how come we all get lumped together? Are there any plans to break them apart?

Engineering SE currently seems to be de facto almost exclusively mechanical engineering. [Twenty times more questions are tagged mechanical engineering as process engineering for example](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tags). With that ratio, its pretty likely that a process engineering question drops off the first page of results. As a result, [half of the process engineering questions go unanswered.](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-engineering)

Why was engineering set up this way? Are there plans to subdivide it later?

Comment: Engineering's a small site. Breaking it up could result in even smaller sites that would struggle to survive.

Comment: To put this another way... If Engineering.SE gets to the point where it's getting 3,000 questions per day, I could see it becoming a bit of a headache; arguably, CS.SE and SE.SE only exist because SO got too big to properly support fringe disciplines.

Answer (score 3):

> Why was engineering set up this way?

You can take a look at this page, [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453?phase=definition) and [commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453?phase=commitment) that might help you understand how the site was created and launched into beta.

> Are there plans to subdivide it later?

I think you should ask this question on Engineering SE's Meta as they will have more core users than here. As @HDE226868 mentioned in the comment, breaking it up might not be a good idea when Engineering SE has not even graduated from beta yet. But I think the right procedure would be make a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and see how users respond if you have an idea for a new Stack Exchange site.

[English Language Learners SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) was set up to take care of English learners' questions from [English Language and Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/). As far as I understand, there was a big debate on this issue. I believe there would be pros and cons on subdividing Engineering SE.